# POST request with preflight contains allowed origin but errors that origin is not allowed

Tags: rest, post, fetch-api

I am sending a POST request to a server that I own and have access to.

This triggers a CORS preflight request with OPTIONS method and returns the following response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Allow: HEAD,POST,GET,OPTIONS
Last-modified: Mon, 26 Jun 2017 13:57:08 BST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: origin, content-type, accept, authorization
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Set-Cookie
Content-Type: application/vnd.sun.wadl+xml
Content-Length: 1126
```

The subsequent POST request then reports

`Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/reservation. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

using javascript `fetch`.

As noted above, a POST to my `/reservation` endpoint results in such an error. However POST requests to other endpoints on my server are successful and do not fail reporting that the origin is not allowed. Both execute the same `fetch` code; issue OPTIONS preflight and then POST.

```
var RestRequest = {

    post: function(endpoint, payload, callback, secondCallback) {

        fetch('http://localhost:8080/api' + endpoint, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            method: 'post',
            credentials: 'include',
            body: payload
        })
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then( function (result) {
            callback(result)
            if (secondCallback != null) {
                secondCallback()
            }
        })
    }
};
```

Why is my browser complaining that the origin making the request is not allowed access when a CORS preflight clearly allowed access to this specific origin?

Modifying my server CORS response filters to allow all origins results in the same error message. Making the same requests from the Postman plugin succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

It says the response had HTTP status code 500, so it's different from the response you've posted (which is HTTP 200).

Most likely you have a server error, which prevents the CORS headers to be added to the response.

Comment: The status code 200 was from the CORS preflight OPTIONS request.

Comment: Right sorry I didn't notice, however the issue is still the same. If there's a 500 error on your server, the headers are not going to be sent. So the issue you have is not with CORS but some other bug on your server.

Comment: There is no bug on the server because using Postman to issue the exact same request succeeds. It seems like it could be an issue with javascript's `fetch` api as using `unirest` to handle the REST requests also succeeds. The 500 code seems to come from an incomplete POST request, causing the server to throw a 500 after the fact as it expects a body in the POST request and didn't receive one as the browser cut the procedure when it realised the origin wasn't allowed. In this case, I'm not sure why any kind of POST request made it to the server if it wasn't allowed.

Comment: @Shiri, could you post the Postman request that works and the `fetch` one that doesn't? I assume `fetch` works fine but you need to set it up correctly. You might still want to look at the 500 though since if fetch issues an incomplete request, the server should respond 400 (user error) and not 500 (server error). That might also tell you what the issue is with the fetch request.

Comment: I've updated my question to include the code and an important piece of missing information regarding this. Other uses of the `fetch` block succeeds perfectly but only fails with origin access not allowed for one endpoint of mine. You are right about the server's incorrect response codes and I will look to handle it better, but the underlying issue that the client issues an incomplete request after reporting that the origin was not allowed for _some_ requests is still a very bizarre inconsistency.