# Access-Control-Allow-Origin works for OPTIONS preflight but not POST that came after

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm encountering an issue where my preflight OPTIONS request gets a 200, but my POST request that came after returned a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`.

Right now in my back-end code the relevant bits I have in my `index.js` look like this

```js
...
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

const suggestions = require("./routes/suggestions");
const metainfo = require("./routes/metainfo");
const playlist = require("./routes/playlist");
const download = require("./routes/download");

app.use(suggestions);
app.use(metainfo);
app.use(playlist);
app.use(download);
...
```

and then my `download.js`, which uses a POST that triggers a preflight request

```js
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/download", async (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

I thought that would give enough headers for both OPTIONS and POST and basically any other method, but somehow GET and OPTIONS work, but not POST . . .

I've googled around and found these 2 posts.

[CORS preflight return Access-Control-Allow-Origin but response hangs on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733219/cors-preflight-return-access-control-allow-origin-but-response-hangs-on)

[POST request with preflight contains allowed origin but errors that origin is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44760601/post-request-with-preflight-contains-allowed-origin-but-errors-that-origin-is-no)

but they could only tell me what I need to do, not how I need to do it. It sounded like I needed to copy paste the first 2 lines of `index.js` into `download.js`, so I went and tried that, ie:

```js
const router = express.Router();
router.post("/download", async (req, res) => {
  app.use(cors());
  app.options('*', cors());
  ...
});
```

but that didn't work for me either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: I am well aware that setting '*' for cors is bad, especially with Access-Control-Allow-Origin, ie. the very thing I'm trying to fix. But this is just a test project, and I'm only focussing on somehow fixing the POST to run.

EDIT #2: Adding request/response debug + front end code as requested

Front-end code that sends the POST request

```js
await axios({
  url: "https://mysite.fakeurl/download",
  method: "POST",
  responseType: "blob",
  data: { extraData: someData },
});
```

Preflight request

```html
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: shirokatake-ytdl-backend.herokuapp.com
Origin: https://shirokatake.github.io
Referer: https://shirokatake.github.io/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36
```

Preflight response

```html
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 11 Feb 2022 16:22:55 GMT
Server: Cowboy
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Via: 1.1 vegur
X-Powered-By: Express
```

POST request

```html
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 23
Content-Type: application/json
DNT: 1
Host: shirokatake-ytdl-backend.herokuapp.com
Origin: https://shirokatake.github.io
Referer: https://shirokatake.github.io/
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="98", "Google Chrome";v="98"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.82 Safari/537.36
```

POST response

```html
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 506
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 11 Feb 2022 16:23:24 GMT
Server: Cowboy
```

Comment: Go look at the network tab of the Chrome inspector/debugger when this request is sent from your browser. That will show you EXACTLY what the communication is between your browser and your server around this request. If that doesn't immediately show you what's wrong and you want more help from us, then post the two requests and two responses from your server as they appear in the network tab of the debugger.  Also, include your client-side code that constructs the request and sends it.  Right now, this is an abstract question without any debugging info.  You need to make it a lot less abstract.

Comment: The preflight response is always 200 OK, what matters are the `Access-Control-*` headers in that response.

Comment: Added extra stuffs @jfriend00

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `app.use(cors());` is BEFORE your `/download` route handler?  From the response you're getting back to the client, It appears it is not so that it doesn't run before your route handler runs.

Comment: FYI, you can also do: `router.post("/download", cors(), async (req, res) => {   ...  });` while keeping the `app.options()` you have for handling the pre-flight.  This will ensure that the cors middleware runs for this request handler.

Comment: Also, why is there no `content-type` header in the POST request that tells the server what kind of data your are posting in the body?  There should be.  You're sending data and the server needs to know what kind of data.  The `content-type` also affects pre-flight in the browser.

Comment: Yes, you can see it in the first snippet, `app.use(cors())` is before everything. Also yes, there is a `content-type` header for POST, it's on line 6 of POST request (`application/json`). I've also tried adding `cors()` where you suggested but it also didn't work. If you want I can link you the repo so you can have a closer look . . .

Comment: Another thing is it was working before this. But I tried reverting my repo back to the commit that worked, but for some reason it also didn't work . . . I don't know what is wrong ><

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm running into a very similar issue right now.